# FastMM: how can I RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak for all unicode or ansi strings?

Tags: delphi, fastmm

There are three functions to register an expected memory leak in fastmm:

```
function FastMM_RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(ALeakedPointer: Pointer): Boolean; overload;
function FastMM_RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(ALeakedObjectClass: TClass; ACount: Integer = 1): Boolean; overload;
function FastMM_RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(ALeakedBlockSize: NativeInt; ACount: Integer = 1): Boolean; overload;
```

but they are no applicable for string types.
Any idea ?

Comment: String are reference counted. They are freed automatically. Could you give an example of the case you try to detect?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier not to leak the strings?

Comment: Often it is an object with string properties that is leaked. Fix the object leak and the string leaks will go away as well.

Comment: #David: that is what I want to achieve

Comment: #Brian: the problem is that there are no object leaks but true unicode leaks from wherever they may come

Comment: #fpiette: there is no example to provide, they are popping up from anywhere so I would like to hide them

Comment: @Jürgen, it would be extremely useful to have [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) to look at.

Comment: @Serhii: sorry, no chance to provide a reproducible example. Its a huge application and the leak message comes now and then. Unfortunately, the stacktrace gives not a reference to my source code. So what would help me is a possibility to register unicode string leaks to be excepted leaks, like I quoted in the headline of this thread...

Answer (score 0):

You can register these leaks as generic leaks, using
`function FastMM_RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(ALeakedBlockSize: NativeInt; ACount: Integer = 1): Boolean; overload;`

Here is an example:

```
program StringLeakDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  FastMM5,
  System.SysUtils;

const Leakee = 'string which leaks';
var Z: ^String;

begin
  FastMM_MessageBoxEvents := [Low(TFastMM_MemoryManagerEventType) .. High(TFastMM_MemoryManagerEventType)];
  FastMM_RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak(32 + Length(Leakee), 1);

  GetMem(Z, SizeOf(string));
  Z^ := Leakee;
  FreeMem(Z);
end.
```

Comment: ok, but this is a solution just for a known fixed size string. But I am looking for a possibilty to exclude all unicode string leaks of any size...

Comment: It seem to undermine the whole idea of leak checking, but if you still wish to do so,
there seem to be no other way except modifying FastMM5.pas so that it will not report string leaks.